# Typescript - Element implicity has an 'any' error when trying to access a value from an enum

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get the cleanest answer from this problem.
I've got a parameter that can be either a number or a (valid) string, and I'm using it as index to get the value of a declared enum.

Because Typescript does not know the value of the string, it throws:
*Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.ts(7015)*

I believe the use of *any*, as we can see in the *validWithArg2* is dirty and buggy.

What could be a cleaner solution to that?

The code I used as reference:

````
     const f = (numberOrStringParam: number | string, stringParam: string, numberParam: number) => {
        enum EnumDeclaration {
            'ATV' = 1,
            'OLV' = 2,
            'DC' = 3,
        }

        const validWithNumber = EnumDeclaration[0];
        const validWithString = EnumDeclaration['ATV'];

        // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.ts(7015)
        const invalidWithArg = EnumDeclaration[numberOrStringParam];
        // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.ts(7015)
        const invalidWithArg2 = EnumDeclaration[stringParam];
        const validWithArg = EnumDeclaration[numberParam];
        const validWithArg3 = EnumDeclaration[numberParam as any];

        return {
            invalidWithArg,
            invalidWithArg3,
            validWithArg,
            validWithArg2,
            validWithNumber,
            validWithString,
        };
    };```
````

Comment: "number or a (valid) string" valid? How's the compiler supposed to know that? How do *you* know that? I don't see any conditional checks or use of the `in` operator. You can't index an enum with a random string. Also, you have the enum hidden in a closure which completely defeats the point of using one...what are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Never mind where the enum was placed, it was just an example. Definitely not the place for it tho, yes.
That was my hole point. I didn't know how to let Typescript know that I wanted to access the enum with a valid key. Alexander Kosykh answered the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
enum EnumDeclaration {
  'ATV' = 1,
  'OLV' = 2,
  'DC' = 3,
}

type EnumDeclarationType = Partial<typeof EnumDeclaration>;

const f = (numberOrStringParam: number | keyof EnumDeclarationType, stringParam: number | keyof EnumDeclarationType, numberParam: number) => {

  const validWithNumber = EnumDeclaration[0];
  const validWithString = EnumDeclaration['ATV'];

  const invalidWithArg  = EnumDeclaration[numberOrStringParam];
  const invalidWithArg2 = EnumDeclaration[stringParam];
  const validWithArg = EnumDeclaration[numberParam];
  const validWithArg3 = EnumDeclaration[numberParam];

  return {
      invalidWithArg2,
      validWithArg,
      validWithNumber,
      validWithString,
  };
};

f('ATV','OLV', 3)
```